# Jscrollpane scroll div when not hovering over it

Tags: scroll, hover, jscrollpane

I have only one div that needs scrolling with Jscrollpane on a page.

Currently the div is only scrollable when hovering over it.I want to be able to scroll that div even if the mouse is not over the div.

I don't want the page itself to scroll at all.

Thanks.